# Fetch boto3 credentials only from EC2 instance profile

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

The `boto3` [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#configuring-credentials) lists the order in which credentials are searched and the credentials are fetched from the EC2 instance metadata service only at the very last.

How do I force `boto3` to fetch the credentials only from the EC2 instance profile or the instance metadata service?

I came across [this](https://gist.github.com/fiunchinho/70a5d53198e25df65ca6) which lets me get the temporary credentials from the metadata service and then I could pass this on to create a `boto3` session.

However my question is whether there is a better way to do this? Is it possible to create a `boto3` session by specifying the `provider` to use ie `InstanceMetadataProvider` - [link](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/5e044f7b94acb83fce4265b5ce47620db70a9876/botocore/credentials.py#L829)? I tried searching the docs a lot, but couldn't figure it out.

The reason - the context under which this script runs also has environment variables with AWS keys set which would obviously take precedence, however I need the script to run only with the IAM role assigned to the EC2 instance.

Comment: Is your intention is not have aws credentials on file. If you are okay with that then we can use --profile profile-name and if profile flag isn't given IAM role can be used.

Comment: Yep, I don't want to worry about managing the AWS credentials or set up a profile. The instance IAM role assigned to the node has the required permissions for the script to run.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on ```we can use `--profile profile-name` and if profile flag isn't given IAM role can be used```

If I don't give a `profile` it will prefer the AWS creds in the environment variables already set in the context the script runs. 

How do I force the EC2 instance role to be chosen by `boto3`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I ended up doing this, works as expected. Always uses the temp creds from the instance role. The script is short-lived so the validity of the creds is not an issue.

```
from botocore.credentials import InstanceMetadataProvider, InstanceMetadataFetcher

provider = InstanceMetadataProvider(iam_role_fetcher=InstanceMetadataFetcher(timeout=1000, num_attempts=2))
creds = provider.load().get_frozen_credentials()
client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='us-east-1', aws_access_key_id=creds.access_key, aws_secret_access_key=creds.secret_key, aws_session_token=creds.token)
```

If there is a better way to do, please feel free to post.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use boto3.

```
>>> session = boto3.Session(region_name='foo_region')
>>> credentials = session.get_credentials()
>>> credentials = credentials.get_frozen_credentials()
>>> credentials.access_key
u'ABC...'
>>> credentials.secret_key
u'DEF...'
>>> credentials.token
u'ZXC...'
>>> access_key = credentials.access_key
>>> secret_key = credentials.secret_key
```

It's a similar idea, but I find it returns much faster

Comment: This doesn't force EC2 instance profile credentials. It just grabs the keys and the token from the initialized session.

Comment: @TuukkaMustonen Those keys and token from the session are based on the EC2 instance creds though. When the EC2 is initialized with an IAM role, it doesn't have a separate cred like an individual does. getting the frozen credentials from the instance's session is the only way to get the cred for use elsewhere

Comment: Yes, it will show the EC2 instance profile credentials IF the session was initialized with those. But if you read OP's description (last paragraph), you can see he has AWS credentials as environment variables and the session in your example would initialize with the environment variables, and not using the EC2 instance profile, which is really what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import boto3
import botocore

botocore_session = botocore.session.get_session()
credential_provider = botocore_session.get_component('credential_provider')
instance_metadata_provider = credential_provider.get_provider('iam-role')
credential_provider.insert_before('env', instance_metadata_provider)
boto3_session = boto3.Session(botocore_session=botocore_session)

client = boto3_session.client(...)
resource = boto3_session.resource(...)
```